# Cannot run python script - ImportError: No module named '_chipset'

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I am trying to run the quick_dump.py which is a member script of [intel-gpu-tools](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools); The thing every time I input :

```
$sudo python3 quick_dump.py
```

I get this output as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/chipset.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_chipset', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_chipset'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick_dump.py", line 17, in <module>
    import chipset
  File "/usr/local/bin/chipset.py", line 28, in <module>
    _chipset = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/bin/chipset.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _chipset
ImportError: No module named '_chipset'
```

...I do suspect there is something wrong with python version or dependence lib or the way I call the script is not correct or I don't know... So I do need your help how to find out the reason and
fix the issue to make possible start the script

**EDIT :**

> chipset.i should reside in same directory

I download sources and go to tools/quick_dump folder (there is chipset.i) then I try to start script as: `$sudo python3 quick_dump.py` 
but I get this output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick_dump.py", line 17, in <module>
    import chipset
  File "/home/.../quick_dump/intel-gpu-tools/tools/quick_dump/chipset.py", 

    line 28, in <module>
        _chipset = swig_import_helper()
      File "/home/.../quick_dump/intel-gpu-tools/tools/quick_dump/chipset.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_chipset', fp, pathname, description)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    ImportError: /home/.../quick_dump/intel-gpu-tools/tools/quick_dump/_chipset.so: undefined symbol: _Ux86_64_getcontext
```

p.s. OS linux

Thanks

Comment: why are usind `sudo python` ?

Comment: just in case :) but still the result is the same as with sudo or not in the mentioned case

Comment: check `which python` and `sudo which python`

Comment: @itzmeontv Concerning the version "$python -V" outputs "Python 3.4.2" and the "$which python" outputs "/usr/bin/python"

Answer (score 0):

[chipset.i](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/intel-gpu-tools/tree/tools/quick_dump) should reside in same directory.